# Macro trigger in TeXstudio does not work

Tags: macros, texstudio

I am trying to define a `macro` in `TeXstudio`.

When I am typing "itemslide" nothing happens.. Only when I am typing "\itemslide" the text is replaced by the content of "LaTeX-Text".

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Works for me... 
Just in case this is the problem try pressing ok (as in to close the edit macro window) and then type `\itemslide` and press enter. If that does not work try pressing the run command from the edit macro window and see what happens

Comment: Hey, `\itemslide` does work for me too. But shouldn't it also work by typing only `itemslide` without slash?

Comment: I saw this in the manual `The "abbreviation" is a pseudo-command for the latex completer. If the pseudo-command is completed, the macro will be inserted instead. Note that the pseudo-command needs to start with a backslash ("\")` not sure if that helps other than assert that `\itemslide` should work

Comment: Ok, thanks. That helps a lot. So, what is the `trigger` for?

Comment: The manual says this about trigger: `"Trigger" is a regular expression which triggers the inclusion of the macro: When the last written characters match this expression, they are removed and the macro is inserted/executed.` and then after that it says

Comment: `In its simplest form, the trigger is simply a text, which is replaced by the macro. E.g. trigger="eg" macro="example given", "eg" in "the leg" is replaced on pressing "g" by "example given"
As the trigger is a regular expression, more elaborate triggers can be created. TXS makes use of look-behind searching: "(?<=\s)%" is used to replace a "%" if the previous character is a space.`

Comment: I unfortunately still don't understand why the input of `itemslide` does not trigger the trigger.. :/

Comment: after modifying your macro, try restarting your texstudio (I think this is a bug) and try again.

Comment: @mrbela any updates here?

Comment: @Troy You are right. I have to restart TXS to make the trigger work.